# I can't get request payload when used $auth.signup(user)

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-restserver, satellizer

I have a problem with satellizer api signup, when call the method $auth.signup(user) in my backend made with CodeIgniter I can't retrieve the values sent in user.

I tried everything

The methos of my library REST for options call

`$this->options('name'); // this is null`

[link](https://github.com/chriskacerguis/codeigniter-restserver) library

I tried get payload manually with this

`$request_body = file_get_contents('php://input');`

`$data = json_decode($request_body); //this is null too`

I don't know that can be please, help me!

Thank you all!!
Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed and the solutions is [here](https://github.com/sahat/satellizer/issues/430)

Summarizing, the browser send two request one OPTIONS for check if the server accept custom headers and after request POST with data.

Thanks for your time!